# Failure to verify openssl signatures in PHP

Tags: php, openssl, digital-signature, public-key

If I use openssl to create a new key pair, use the private key to sign some data, and use the public key to verify the signature... it works.

```
$ openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024
$ openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mypubkey.pem
$ echo 'It could be bunnies' > file.txt
$ openssl rsautl -sign -in file.txt -inkey mykey.pem -out sig.txt
$ openssl rsautl -verify -in sig.txt -inkey mypubkey.pem -pubin
It could be bunnies
```

However, if I try to verify the signature using the openssl library in php it fails.

```
$pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('/var/key/mypubkey.pem')); 
$sig = file_get_contents('/var/key/sig.txt');
$data = file_get_contents('/var/key/file.txt');
$verifyResult = (openssl_verify($data, $sig, $pubkey) == 1);
```

Similar story with Crypt_RSA

```
$pubkey = file_get_contents('/var/test/mypubkey.pem');
$sig = file_get_contents('/var/test/sig.txt');
$data = file_get_contents('/var/test/file.txt');
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($pubkey);
$rsa->verify($data, $sig);
$verifyResult = $rsa->verify($data, $sig);
```

How do I get php to play nicely? These examples are simplified but accurate to my needs. In the real world I will only have the data, signature, and public key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For phpseclib, try $rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1) before calling $rsa->verify().

Comment: The current Crypt_RSA documentation seemed to suggest that PKCS1 was the default. However, I did not try explicitly calling setSignatureMode before the verify so you may very well be correct. Giving you the benefit of the doubt (and the checkmark) since my code has moved on and it's now inconvenient to test. Thanks for the response...

Comment: The default is CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PSS.  It offers better security but is not as compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I was really hoping someone would chime in with a definitive answer on the public key question. Seems like it should work. However, in the meantime, I've switched from a public key to a self-signed certificate. The openssl library in PHP seems happy with extracting an acceptable public key from that. Which means the real problem (verifying signed data) is solved for me. Server clients will now have the data, signature, and x.509 certificate.

Here are the code snippet(s).

```
$ openssl genrsa -out server.key 4096
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
$ openssl dgst -sha1 -sign server.key -out file.sha1 file.txt
```

...

```
$pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('/var/key/server.crt')); 
$sig = file_get_contents('/var/key/file.sha1');
$data = file_get_contents('/var/key/file.txt');
$verifyResult = (openssl_verify($data, $sig, $pubkey) == 1);
```